# How can I know that a JS or HTML or CSS file is well formatted via bash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I know I can open a code editor and see the file and realize if it's formatted or not. But I want to create a script that does that. I want to search through a directory and find all of the files that are not formatted.

I know the formatting of each file differs. For example, to format Python you need a different set of rules and to format a JS or a C# file different rules apply.

However, since code editors do it behind the scene using some extensions or code-parser engines, I think there might be tools for shell too.

Can I do it? Can I install some dependencies and then search through code files in a directory and report the list of files that are not code-formatted?

Comment: Not sure if there is a one size fits all solution to this, since code formatting is highly opinionated.

Comment: For JS, HTML and CSS, you might consider [Prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: use the extension [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) to apply formatting to the whole workspace

Comment: what do you want to do in bash if you detect the file is not formatted? Make a copy of the file, format the copy, compare with original.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html) to your project, then run command to check unformatted files:

`npx prettier --check .`

To format your code, run:

`npx prettier --write .`